# Tabulator: how can I get the index of recently added rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a Tabulator table where I add new rows (at top position) via

```
$("#add-row").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "row-edit.php", // add row into DB
      data: "typ=add",
      type: "POST",
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error){
        alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + "; " + error);
      }
    })
    table.addRow({});
});
```

I now want to retrieve the index of this new row to update cells.

```
cellEdited:function(cell){
  //this is called whenever a cell's value is edited.
  var id = cell.getRow().getIndex(); // get indeox of updated row
  ...
}
```

However, after adding this row the index is undefined. So I think i need to reload the data but I'm not sure what's the best way to do it.

I have added this line right before the `table.addRow({});`:

```
table.replaceData("refresh.php");
```

This in general works and I'd get the index of the row. But the newly added row immediately disappears from the screen - as I found out this is because I have vaidators in use which now fail on some empty cells of the new row.
If I remove the validators the added row stays visible and can be updated successfully.

Is there another way to get the index of the new row to allow updating?
My plan B now would be to add some placeholder values into the added row so that the validators don't fail. But I would prefer to have a new empty row w/o any data in it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when load data from sql connection. The index of inserted row was undefined when i click on it or change its value.

i haven't try it with Ajax but SqlConnection on node.js backend

What worked for me:

1. When i call my method to insert new row, first trigger sql database to create a new empty entry... lets say insert all values of my object with null or "" except primary key which is auto increment.
2. Then reload your tabulator table to fetch new line direct from sql (i think reloading ajax should be the same as refresh.php)
3. Now when you will use tabulator's callback `cellEdited:function(cell){}` you can return index using `row.getIndex();` (in my case getIndex was my sql's row primary key)

Also keep in mind that tabulator has these pretty methods: `table.replaceData("/data.php") //load data from data/php via ajax request`

you can find more information on this specific problem [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/update)

i hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

The ***addRow*** function returns a promise that resolves with the [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/components#component-row) for the new row. You can call any function you like on that row to manipulate it, in this case the ***getPosition*** function will return its position in the table:

```js
table.addRow({})
.then((row) => {
    var position = row.getPosition(); //get position of row
});
```